Deduplicate values in the df based on the previous/next row
Consider this df:
import pandas as pd
d = {"a":["Residency", "Citizenship", "Citizenship","Residency",
          "Citizenship","Citizenship","Citizenship","Residency"],
     "b":["UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

--
             a   b
0    Residency  UK
1  Citizenship  UK
2  Citizenship  UK
3    Residency  UK
4  Citizenship  UK
5  Citizenship  UK
6  Citizenship  UK
7    Residency  UK

I would like to replace Citizenship and UK with None if the previous value in a is not Residency. Bear in mind that there are many other columns in this df that would need to stay the same. So the end result would be:
             a     b
0    Residency    UK
1  Citizenship    UK
2         None  None
3    Residency    UK
4  Citizenship    UK
5         None  None
6         None  None
7    Residency    UK


Having a doubt about your comment, do you want to avoid masking the other columns or also mask them?

thanks @mozway Didn't need masking for other cols in this case but good to know how it can be achieved

Use a boolean mask and propagate it to the next row with shift:
m = df['a'].eq('Residency')
df.loc[~(m|m.shift()), ['a', 'b']] = None

Output:
             a     b  other
0    Residency    UK  other
1  Citizenship    UK  other
2         None  None  other
3    Residency    UK  other
4  Citizenship    UK  other
5         None  None  other
6         None  None  other
7    Residency    UK  other

Or if you have other columns and also want to mask them:
m = df['a'].eq('Residency')
df.loc[~(m|m.shift())] = None

Output:
             a     b  other
0    Residency    UK  other
1  Citizenship    UK  other
2         None  None   None
3    Residency    UK  other
4  Citizenship    UK  other
5         None  None   None
6         None  None   None
7    Residency    UK  other

Intermediates:
             a   b      m m.shift()  m|m.shift()  ~(m|m.shift())
0    Residency  UK   True       NaN         True           False
1  Citizenship  UK  False      True         True           False
2  Citizenship  UK  False     False        False            True
3    Residency  UK   True     False         True           False
4  Citizenship  UK  False      True         True           False
5  Citizenship  UK  False     False        False            True
6  Citizenship  UK  False     False        False            True
7    Residency  UK   True     False         True           False

Alternatively, if the values after "Residency" are always duplicated, another option could be to mask the successive identical values:
df.loc[df['a'].eq(df['a'].shift()), ['a', 'b']] = None

